# How I can read nested array at JSON file by SWIFT 2

Tags: ios, json, swift2

I wrote this code to read country at table view from this JSON file :

JSON:

```
[5]
   0:  {
        "country": "Afghanistan"
        "code": "AF"
       }-
  1:  {
        "country": "Åland Islands"
        "code": "AX"
      }-
  2:  {
        "country": "Albania"
        "code": "AL"
      }-
  3:  {
        "country": "Algeria"
        "code": "DZ"
      }-
  4:  {
        "country": "American Samoa"
        "code": "AS"
   }
```

My code :

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableCountryView: UITableView!
var json_url = "........ my url here ......... "

var TableData:Array< datastruct > = Array < datastruct >()

enum ErrorHandler:ErrorType
{
    case ErrorFetchingResults
}


struct datastruct
{
    var country_name:String?
    var country_code:String?


    init(add: NSDictionary)
    {
        country_name = add["country"] as? String
        country_code = add["code"] as? String
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tableCountryView.dataSource = self
    tableCountryView.delegate = self
    get_data_from_url(json_url)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return TableData.count

}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let data = TableData[indexPath.row]


    cell.textLabel?.text = data.country_name! + " - " + data.country_code!


    return cell
   }


func get_data_from_url(url:String)
{


    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData


    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (
        let data, let response, let error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.extract_json(data!)
            return
        })

    }

    task.resume()

}



func extract_json(jsonData:NSData)
{
    let json: AnyObject?
    do {
        json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: [])
    } catch {
        json = nil
        return
    }

    if let list = json as? NSArray
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.count ; i++ )
        {
            if let data_block = list[i] as? NSDictionary
            {

                TableData.append(datastruct(add: data_block))
            }
        }



        do_table_refresh()

    }


}

func do_table_refresh()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.tableCountryView.reloadData()
        return
    })
}


}
```

This code is working true for the first JSON syntax but if I want to read sub-array like the syntax at the following JSON file , how I can edit that in my previous code.

JSON:

```
{
"Countries": [4]
0:  {
     "countryname": "Egypt"
     "code": "20"
    }-
1:  {
     "countryname": "India"
     "code": "91"
    }-
2:  {
     "countryname": "United States"
     "code": "1"
    }-
3:  {
     "countryname": "Turkey"
     "code": "90"
    }-
   }
```

Also I have the button at my storyboard and I want to show this table view of country when clicking on this button and then choose one country and close this table and show the result on the button , I know this easy but I started to learn IOS from 2 weeks only, I hope if you can give me advice in these cases.

Comment: Generally in JSON, arrays have their contents nested inside. Is this a response from a server ? or are you just making your own json file for your progrram to read from

Comment: the first JSON file is ready from one tutorial but the second JSON file this my json file on my server

Comment: You should check where your code is failing, using prints, breakpoints or writing some tests (best approach). I would start from the do-catch block in the extract_json function.

Comment: Moreover, if the problem is in json parsing, there are plenty of json parsing libraries on github, there's no need to reinvent the wheel.